# Is it possible to call a function and only getting the value on a variable without it printing

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example I make a function like this:

`

```py
def printnums(num1, num2):
    print(num1, num2)
    return(num1, num2)
```

Which I then call on a variable

```py
x = printnums(1, 2)
```

Output:

`3`

Now I don't want that 3 to print as I call it, I want it to only print out when use `print(x)` which will only then give me 3. And the function in question is os.system().

Since I am also a beginner in cpp I thought that just declaring the function as a void `x = void printnums()` but it didn't work. Of course after not being able to solve the problem on my own I turned to google but I couldn't find anything. The only post I did find was for python 2.7 but it still didn't help me.

Edit: Yes I know that I can just remove the print statement but I'm using a function from a module that I cannot change. If you read everything that I wrote you would see that I'm talking about os.system()!!!

Comment: Define the function without the `print(num1, num2)`.

Comment: Why not just remove the print statement?

Comment: You can't call *that* function without it printing something, because the function has a `print` built into it.  But nothing requires you to put a `print` inside every function (and in fact most people will discourage you from doing so, for the exact reason that it makes it impossible to call the function without having it print).

Comment: They doesn't output 3.

Comment: @Samwise *"You can't call that function without it printing"* - You mean you can't call it without it calling whatever is at that time bound to the name `print` :-)

Comment: In general, python won't do anything you don't ask it to do. If it were... you may want to hide for the rise of the machines is coming. BTW that includes adding 1 and 2 before printing them.

Comment: `os.system` doesn't print a darned thing.  Perhaps you should show us the exact example you're worried about.  If you want to fetch the command's output, then you should use the `subprocess` module instead.  It is far more flexible.

Comment: From [`os.system` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.system): "If command generates any output, it will be sent to the interpreter standard output stream."

Answer (score 0):

You could have an optional parameter which enables printing:

```py
def printnums(num1, num2, output=False):
    if output:
       print(num1, num2)
    return(num1, num2)

x = printnums(1, 2)
y = printnums(3, 4, True)
```

Output:

```py
3, 4
```